# Put content into my "popup" boxes. HTML CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to write my first javascript and it seems to work fine but I can't find how to get HTML content into the popup that the script creates. Would appresiate some help to find the issue or maybe how I should rewrite the code.

I got two buttons to work but when I try anything else it just wont.

The whole HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<center><img id="header" src="../img/hemsidotitle.png"></img></center>
<div id="shadow">
    <div id="navbar">
        <a id="navbar-button" href="../index.html" style="border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px">Hem</a>
        <a id="navbar-button" href="../donera.html">Donera</a>
        <a id="navbar-button" href="#">Kits</a>
        <a id="navbar-button" href="#" style="border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px">Kontakta</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main-container">
        <a onclick="myFunction()" id="kit-drake" class="kit">click me</a>
        <div>
        <script>
            function submit(){
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-popup" class="pay"><input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Köp Nu" onClick="submit()"></input> </div>';

            }
        </script>
        <div id="demo"></div>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-popup" ><input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Avbryt" onClick="submit()"><a id="pay-button" href="#">Köp Nu</a> </div>';
            }
        </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-center">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the whole HTML file?

Comment: Done, just posted the whole HTML

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do your HTML outside of a  tag since that's inline-Javascript and NOT Html.  This can be achieved using multiple different tags but i'll give you one to start out with that prints out "Hello world!":

```
<a onclick="myFunction()" id="kit-drake" class="kit"></a>
<div id="demo">   
<p>Hello world!</p>  
<script>
    function submit(){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-popup" class="pay"><input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Köp Nu" onClick="submit()"></input> </div>';

    }
</script>
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-    popup" ><input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Avbryt" onClick="submit()"><a id="pay-button" href="#">Köp Nu</a> </div>';
    }
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thoose things you did showed before I pressed the anchor. Then when I pressed it the div="kit-drake-popup" came up empty. I'm looking for to put content to the kit-drake-popup div. Not outside it. Sorry for being missleading.

Answer (score 0):

is it what you want ? I tried to clean a bit your code too.

```
<a id="kit-drake" class="kit" href="#">Click me ! </a>
<div id="demo"></div>

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="kit-drake-popup" ><input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Avbryt" onClick="submit()"><a id="pay-button" href="#">Köp Nu</a> </div>';
    document.getElementById ("kit-drake-popup").addEventListener("click",submit, false);
}
 function submit(){
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML+= '<div id="kit-drake-popup" class="pay"><input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Köp Nu" onClick="submit()"></input> </div>';    



            }
document.getElementById ("kit-drake").addEventListener("click",myFunction, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yvs38upf/

Comment: Ye almost. Let's say I want to add a img for example in the popup, where shall I put it? Tried the demo div, didnt work.

Comment: I dont know where you want to add it , but you can do it like that.
https://jsfiddle.net/nkvyjhj3/
You can also use another button or whatever you want

Comment: When I click the anchor the div id="kit-drake-popup" shows up like this: http://gyazo.com/e9539040942c8409c1dc4d8d548160c7

To put content in that div is the hard part.